# React js: ref turns into null when I reopen modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code in my snippet:

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useDownloadExcel } from 'react-export-table-to-excel';
import { Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter, Button, Table } from 'reactstrap';
import '../table.css'
import TableManifestData from './tableManifestData';

const ExportManifest = ({input, cardType}) => {
  const tableRef = useRef(null)
  const [centeredModal, setCenteredModal] = useState(false)

  const { onDownload } = useDownloadExcel({
    currentTableRef: tableRef.current,
    filename: 'manifest ku reguler',
    sheet: 'manifest',
  })

  console.log("TABLE REF : ", tableRef.current);

  let tgl = Date.now()

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <a href='#' onClick={() => { setCenteredModal(true) }}>Manifest</a>
      </div>
      <div className='modal-fullscreen'>
        <Modal isOpen={centeredModal} toggle={() => setCenteredModal(!centeredModal)} className='modal-fullscreen'>
          <ModalHeader toggle={() => setCenteredModal(!centeredModal)}>Manifest KU Reguler</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            <div ref={tableRef}>
              <TableManifestData data={input} type={cardType}/>
            </div>
          </ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <Button onClick={onDownload}>Export Manifest</Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ExportManifest
```

When I just start opening my project, the onDownload runs fine as tableRef has its value which is the `<div>` as states below. However, when I close the modal and reopen it - The tableRef turn into null, and the value of tableRef is not null when the condition of the modal is closed. This is my very first time using reference and I am still a beginner at react js, where did I go wrong if I want to keep the value of tableRef no matter the state of the modal or at least accessible when the modal is opened?

**Edit:** apparently, the problem might be because of how I log the table ref there. However, it didn't change when I press the button to run  `onDownload` function which uses the `react-export-table-to-excel` library. At first, it actually downloads the content of

```
<TableManifestData data={input} type={cardType}/>
```

but after I close and reopen the modal, the excel I got will remain `undefined` which I assume the problem is the `tableRef` value.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to **prevent rendering** or when you want to **get the reference** of an element in the dom you can use the **`useRef`**.

In this case, you want to get the reference of an element, but the **element is not in your dom** when the modal is not open. so you have a `null` value at this time.

After your modal opens, there are occur state changes and you have the reference of your `div` element.

**Note:** You realized that your ref depends on the modal toggle state. So it doesn't have a problem.

**Problem:**

Now suppose you have more than one state in this component like the `useDownloadExcel` hook from a third-party library. now it depends on any state changes.

In this case, you can't create `ref` depending on your modal toggle state!

**Solution:**

You want the reference of `div` when the modal is open, so you can move it to another component and it doesn't care what is the modal toggle state.

```js
<div ref={tableRef}>
  <TableManifestData data={input} type={cardType}/>
</div>
```